# CURL не хочет подгружать страницу - PHP

Tags: php, curl

Перепробовал практически все наборы опций курла ... Есть ссылка ... Страница реально существует ...но CURL её не видит ...

```
ini_set('allow_url_fopen','on');
set_time_limit(0);
        $uagent = "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.14";
        $Link = 'https://euroset.ru/kazan/search/?q=LG+G360&filter=all&filter%5B%5D=products';
```

$curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  // возвращает веб-страницу
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);      // не переходит по редиректам
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);          // не возвращает заголовки
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $Link);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);   
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $uagent);
    $str = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    echo $str;</code></pre>

Ну что я опять не так сделал ???

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить возможность перехода по редиректам, установив опции curl:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Там 302 редирект, а вы поставили не переходить по редиректам. Измените этот флаг и все заработает

```
curl -L https://euroset.ru/kazan/search/?q=LG+G360&filter=all&filter%5B%5D=products
```

Отдает страницу без проблем